# PHP - Display results from this 'Detect' array?

Tags: php, arrays, mobile, detect

re:  Home Site = http://mobiledetect.net/
re:  this script = **Mobile_Detect.php**
Download script here:  https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

This script functions perfectly detecting the different parameters of a user's device.

However, this is how I am currently detecting these parameters:

```
// each part of the IF statement is hard-coded = not the way to do this
if($detect->isiOS()){
    $usingOS = 'iOS';
}
if($detect->isAndroidOS()){
    $usingOS = 'Android';
}
echo 'Your OS is: '.$usingOS;
```

My goal is to use a FOREACH to iterate thru the various arrays in this script to determine a user's device's parameters.  I would need to have the "($detect->isXXXXOS())" be dynamic... (which, would be based upon the KEY).  The results would display the KEY.  But the detection would be based upon the VALUE.

Also, since my web page uses a REQUIRE to access this script... in the **Mobile_Script.php** script, the arrays are "protected." I think this is also causing me problems (but I don't know for sure).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Require makes arrays protected? Not got a clue what you mean there.

Comment: Why not use a series of if/else if statements, which will stop once the actual device is found. Whereas a foreach will iterate through them all regardless of when the device type is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use somethin like this:

```
$OSList = $detect->getOperatingSystems();// will give array of operating system name => match params 

foreach($OSList as $os_name=>$os_params/*unused*/)
{
    $method = 'is'.$os_name;
    if($detect->$method())
    {
        $usingOS = $os_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. BUT... Is there a way to have your top $OSList ("i,Windows,Linux") populated from the Mobile_Detect.php script rather than have it hard-coded?

Comment: I have edited my code this should work if there is no syntax errors

Comment: This is working perfectly!  Thank you.  Btw... if you try to use your code from above for the $userAgents array in the Mobile_Detect.php script, it doesn't work.  ??  Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

In `foreach` loop you can call `dynamic method` look like this :

```
$array = array('Android','Windows','Linux','Mac');

foreach( $array as $value) {
   $method = "is{$value}OS";
   if($detect->$method()) {
      $os = $value;
      echo "Your OS is : {$os}";
   } 
}
```

Please rearrange your code what you want. I give you an example.

Comment: Thank you.  BUT... Is there a way to have your top array ('Android','Windows',etc.) populated from the Mobile_Detect.php script rather than have it hard-coded?